# When does $\limsup_{n \to \infty}x_{n} \leq 0$ imply $x_{n} \leq 0$ for large $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, limsup-and-liminf

Let $x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is clear that $x_{n} \leq 0$ for large $n$ (i.e. there is some $N$ such that $x_{n} \leq 0$ for all $n \geq N$) implies $\limsup_{n \to \infty}x_{n} \leq 0$. Since it is convenient to have a shorthand for a phrase of the form "$x_{n} \leq 0$ eventually in $n$ (or for large $n$)", it is tempting to exploit the $\limsup$. Unfortunately, this seems possible if and only if we are dealing with a strict inequality. For a generic inequality, the equality case admits some careful treatment as the sequence $(1/n)$ satisfies $\limsup_{n \to \infty}x_{n} \leq 0$ but there is certainly no $n$ such that $x_{n} \leq 0$.

Now a natural question is under what condition(s) we have the converse? A condition less restrictive in that, for instance, it would not be as long as what is to be shortened, would be a priority.

Comment: So now I don't understand your question, but I am not the one who made the joke.

Comment: The question is clear enough to me.

Comment: @user284331, Hi, I guess you are after an elaboration? I am after an additional condition under which $\limsup x_{n} \leq 0$ implies $x_{n} \leq 0$ eventually. In my opinion, the title pretty much specifies and delineates the question.

Comment: I don't see any other condition than the fact itself that $x_n>0$ only for finitely many $n$.

Comment: If you ask for $\lim \sup x_n <0$, then it is always true. But with a large inequality you are doomed to use much stronger hypothesis I think, such as the one given by amsmath.

Comment: Downvotes are not for questions you find uninteresting but for ones with bad content, in the sense that it is not clear, or it lacks personnal though or whatever. If you know that there is no interesting/suffficient condition, just put that into an answer.@KaboMurphy

Comment: @KaboMurphy, Hi, at least there is some reason. But, if I may, the question is nonetheless not posted at, say, MathOverflow nor is it intended as a formal journal submission, no?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of writing something different (though still equivalent unless $x_n=0$ infinitely often)

> There exist $a_n>0$ such that $\limsup a_nx_n<0$.

Comment: @nicomezi That would only achieve $\limsup a_nx_n\le 0$

Comment: I got it ! Thank you anyway.

Comment: Hi thanks, do you mean less than or equal to in the last inequality?

Comment: @Megadeth: Strict inequality is important. Otherwise, we're back to your original problem.